# Docker mounted folder/file cannot be opened

Tags: python, docker

I have a docker container with a mounted folder via:
-v Z:/Git/Test/neuralNetworkModelFiles/:/app/neuralNetworkModelFiles/

This worked fine all the time until now.

When trying to open a certain file in that folder I get an error file not found. But this file is actually there. This error doesn't happen outside of docker. It doesn't happen for other files.

**Outside docker container:**

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.isfile('20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5')
```

True

```
>>> f = open("20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5")
```

**Inside docker container:**

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.isfile('20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5')
```

True

```
>>> f = open("20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5'

This happens just for this file all other files can be opened. What the heck is that???

Comment: Let's cut Python out of the loop. What does `ls -l 20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5` say, and is it different for this file compared to the others? What about `cat 20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5 | wc -c` (to make sure that it can actually be opened)?

Comment: @Thomas
Inside container:
# ls -l 20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 474848 Feb 11 16:42 20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5
# cat 20210211_163254_d5ec.hdf5 | wc -c
474848
Tried that already. Works.
I just realized this error just happens for the last 2 files in this folder. There are 788 files in it. All files before that 2 files don't throw the error.

Comment: Extremely mysterious! Are you absolutely certain that `os.path.isfile` and `open` are using the same file name (including any invisible characters)? Store the name in a string to be sure.

Comment: @Thomas yes same problem when saved to variable. I just realized this error just happens for the last 2 files in this folder. There are 788 files in it. All files before that 2 files don't throw the error... Seems to be some length problem in Python?

Comment: I assume that under the hood, `os.path.isfile` uses the `stat()` system call, and `open` uses `open()`. Both system calls pass the file name directly to the OS; Python never has to traverse all files in the directory.

Comment: I just noticed you're on Windows. Could it be a case sensitivity thing? I'm not sure how that is handled in Docker... maybe it's inconsistent.

Comment: @Thomas Yes docker is running on a Windows host. I deleted some files and tried to rename it, recreate image/container and so on. Nothing helped. I realized the renaming of the files was not updated consistently in the mounted folder in docker... Then I restarted docker and now it works... I hate docker for things like that.....

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Docker for Windows then. Maybe related to https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9879 or https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7905.